# Elements of pointer to array to another array

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct

So i'm working with this struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    int *grades;
}Student;
```

Where a student has an id and an array of grades that can have between 1 and 40000 elements.

I want to have a function to add a new student, kinda like this:

```
void newSt(int id, int *grades){

    Student st;
    st.id = id;
    /*adding grades*/

    /*other operations I might want to do*/
}
```

But I'm getting a little confused on how to work with pointers and memory allocation, since I know it will never have more than 40000 elements maybe I could do:

```
 st.grades = malloc(40000*sizeof(int);
```

But then I don't know how many elements the array grades I want to add has. I don't think I can't realloc the array grades to 40000 elements because I never alocatted anything. What's the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the size of the array of grades is a problem.  You can't process an array (in C) without knowing it's size.

In terms of dealing with input of unknown size, a standard technique is to allocate malloc a certain amount of memory, then double the allocation each time you need to increase it, but I don't think this is what you're asking about.